# Find the missing 3 numbers

Tags: pattern

Find the missing 3 numbers in the following table:

|  | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **1** | 9 | 6 | 1 | 0 | ? |
| **2** | 8 | 4 | 9 | 1 | ? |
| **3** | 9 | 8 | 2 | 8 | ? |

Comment: Did you make this puzzle yourself, or find it somewhere?

Answer (score 11):

Answer is

> **0,0,0**

Because

> 9 x 8 x 9 = 648
>  6 x 4 x 8 = 192
>  1 x 9 x 2 = 018
>  0 x 1 x 8 = 000
>  or
>  it could also be: **0,0,8** 
>  
>  because since zeros are never used until the end of the puzzle, we don't know if zeros are only used as placeholders and not used to multiply by. The first answer assumes they are used for multiplication.